# Reference for a separation result for proof of triangulability of topological surfaces

Tags: general-topology

In the section of the book, "Riemann Surfaces", by Ahlfors and Sario, that deals with the triangulation of topological surfaces, the authors state without proof, the following result (on pg. 108):

*Let $\gamma$ be a Jordan arc whose interior points lie in a plane region $G$. Then either $\gamma$ does not divide $G$, or it divides $G$ into two subregions. In the latter case, every interior point of $\gamma$ is an accessible boundary point of each subregion.*

(I have given my impression of the precise meaning of the term "accessible boundary point", below; the authors do not define it explicitly.)

Following the statement of this result, the authors write, "This proposition is closely related to the Jordan curve theorem, and will not be proved."

Where can I find a proof this result? I have already checked the book, "Elements of the Topology of Plane Sets of Points", by Newman, and the book, "Topological Analysis", by Whyburn; I did not find the result in either of these books.

If there is no proof that is readily available, how can one prove this result? It is not completely clear what "closely related" means in the authors' reference to the Jordan curve theorem, but presumably some of the techniques used in *some* proof of the latter theorem (e.g., Janizewski's theorem) would be useful in proving the result in question. Note that the region $G$ itself is not assumed to be a Jordan region.

From the application of this result in the proof of the next result in the book, the meaning of "accessible boundary point" is revealed by usage as follows: A boundary point $p$ of a plane region $R$ is accessible if there is a point $r$ in $R$ and a Jordan arc joining $r$ to $p$, whose interior points lie in $R$. (The authors also state, without proof, in their definition of "arcwise connected", that any planar arc joining two points contains a Jordan arc joining them -- but that's a separate issue to resolve and one which I can submit as a separate question.)

Comment: The statement is proved in Theorem 15.24 in Rao's book, Complex Analysis: An Invitation (2nd edition). I'll just add it here for completeness. The book is in general fairly thorough in its treatment of the prime end compactification and Caratheodory's addendum to the Riemann Mapping Theorem.

Comment: As for the final note, I guess that intuitively, if you have an arc connecting two points and it's not a Jordan arc, then it closes a loop at some point. However, you should be able to forget the loops and just "walk straight". I.e. if $\gamma$ makes a loop between times $s$ and $t$, simply glue $\gamma|_{[0,s]}$ to $\gamma|_{[t,1]}$, which will be continuous. Of course, the curve might make infinitely many loops, but you should be able to prove something like "it either only makes countably many loops or it retraces its own path completely at some point". This can be handled similarly.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Why not an official answer?

Comment: For the second part: Because this is barely even a sketch of proof. For the first part: I dunno. I guess I usually reserve actual answers for detailed proofs.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Only the case G = C (complex plane) is covered by Thm. 15.24 in the book by Rao et al.; the given Jordan arc cannot divide G in that case. Do you think that the techniques used in the proof of Thm. 15.24 can also be used to prove the result that I cited? Note that the issue about arcs vs. Jordan arcs, in the definition of accessibility, is circumvented by Proposition 15.27 in the book by Rao et al. (Cf. the discussion following the proof of Thm. 15.24.)

Comment: Well, the proof is local, no? So the proof that any given point on the curve should give rise to two distinct accessible boundary points should just lift without a hitch: Just fix $\delta>0$ such that $B(A,\delta)\subseteq G$ and such that the rest of the argument works.

Comment: If you are wondering about the number of components, note that $\gamma$ must miss some point $z_0$ and so, apply the Riemann mapping theorem to assume wlog that $\gamma$ is a curve in $B(0,1)$, extend it to the one point-compactification of $B(0,1)$ by declaring both end points to be $\infty$, apply $1/z_0$ to move the curve away from $\infty$ and now you have a regular Jordan curve in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Yes, I was wondering about the number of components. However, the Riemann mapping theorem requires that G be simply connected, which is not being assumed.

Comment: Is your author's definition of region just "open and connected"?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Yes, the authors' definition of "region" means just "open and connected".

Answer (score 1):

Although the result itself does not appear to be in the book by Newman, the tools required to prove the result *are* in his book. Results from his book will be cited  in the form, Newman[p]-Theorem C.m.n, where p denotes the page-number, C denotes the chapter number (Roman numeral), m denotes the paragraph number, and n denotes the number of the theorem. For convenience, these results will be summarised, along with some definitions, at the end, in roughly the order of first usage.

It is clear that one only needs to consider the case that $\gamma$ does divide $G$; in which case $G\setminus \gamma$ has at least two components. The proof then consists of three main steps:
(1) $G \setminus \gamma$ has precisely two components;
(2) each interior point of $\gamma$ is a boundary point of each of the two subregions comprising $G \setminus \gamma$; (3) each interior point of $\gamma$ is accessible from each of the two subregions comprising $G \setminus \gamma$.

*Step 1*

We first show that $\gamma$ is a cross-cut of $G$; i.e., that the end-points of $\gamma$ (in $\overline{G}$) lie on $\partial G$. If not, then set $F_1 = \gamma$ and $F_2 = G^c$; $F_1$ and $F_2$ are closed, $F_1$ is bounded and $F_1 \cap F_2$ is connected (it's either empty or a single point --- one end-point of $\gamma$ in $\overline{G}$). Let $x, y$ be any two points in different components of $G\setminus \gamma$. Certainly  $x$ and $y$ are connected in $F^c_2$
and, by Newman[115]-Theorem V.10.1, they are also connected in $F^c_1$. By Newman[112]-Theorem V.9.2, $x$ and $y$ are connected in $(F_1 \cup F_2)^c = G \setminus \gamma$, contrary to the choice of $x$ and $y$. This contradiction yields that $\gamma$ is a cross-cut of $G$.

It remains to show that $G \setminus \gamma$ has at most two components. To prove it, one simply follows Part I of the proof of Newman[115]-Theorem V.10.2 (Jordan Curve Theorem), with a few replacements: In the first sentence of the proof of Part I, on pg. 115, and then throughout that proof, we replace $J$ by $\gamma$, $L_1$ by $\gamma$, $L_2$ by $G^c$, and $\{a, b\}$ by the end-points of $\gamma$ in $\overline{G}$, i.e.,$\{a, b\} = \gamma \cap G^c$ = $L_1 \cap L_2$.
Then the rest of the proof of Part I, onward from the second sentence of that proof, carries through, word for word, to yield that $G \setminus \gamma$ has at most two components.

*Step 2*

The general idea is to remove a small piece of the separating set, $\gamma$,
to allow some path-connectivity between the (former) components of $G\setminus\gamma$ that we denote by $V_1$ and $V_2$; cf.\ the end of the proof of Theorem 36.2 (case $n=1$) in J. Munkres' book, *Elements of Algebraic Topology*.

Choose any two points $q_1, q_2$, with $q_1$ in the component $V_1$ of $G \setminus \gamma$ and $q_2$ in the component $V_2$ of $G \setminus \gamma$, and let $\alpha$ be a path from $q_1$ to $q_2$ in $G\setminus (\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2)$. Then $\alpha^{-1}(\gamma)$ is nonempty because otherwise the connected set $\alpha([0, 1])$ (by the continuity of $\alpha$) would lie entirely in either $V_1$ or $V_2$, contrary to the choice of $\alpha(0)$ and $\alpha(1)$. Also, by the continuity of $\alpha$, $\alpha^{-1}(\gamma)$ is a closed subset of $[0, 1]$ that clearly excludes the end-points $0$ and $1$. Set
$t_1 := \min \alpha^{-1}(\gamma)$ and $t_2 := \max \alpha^{-1}(\gamma)$; $t_1,\ t_2 \neq 0, 1$ and $\alpha(t_i) \in \gamma$ for $i = 1, 2$. Since $\alpha$ lies in $G \setminus (\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2)$), then
$\alpha(t_i) \in \gamma \setminus (\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2) \subset V$, for
$i = 1, 2$.
Therefore, $\alpha(t_i) \in V$, for $i = 1, 2$. By the continuity of $\alpha$, there exists two real values $\tau_1, \tau_2$, with $0 < \tau_1 < t_1$ and
$t_2 < \tau_2 < 1$, such that $\alpha(\tau_i) \in V$, for $i = 1, 2$. Finally, by connectedness and the choice of $\alpha(0)$ and $\alpha(1)$, $\alpha([0, t_1)) \subset V_1$ and $\alpha((t_2, 1]) \subset V_2$. Therefore,
$\alpha(\tau_i) \in V_i$, for $i = 1, 2$. In summary, $p_i := \alpha(\tau_i) \in V_i \cap V$, for $i = 1, 2$.

*Step 3*

Let $p$ be an interior point of $\gamma$ and let $D$ be one of the two domains comprising $G \setminus \gamma$; $\gamma \subset \partial D$. The general idea in proving that $p$ is accessible from $D$ is to create a Jordan region $\Delta$ whose boundary contains $p$ and such that the space $\Delta \cup \{p\}$ contains a neighbourhood $U \cup \{p\}$ of $p$ with $U \subset D$. Since boundary points of any Jordan domain are accessible from it
(Newman[161]-Theorem VI.14.1 and Newman[164]-Theorem VI.14.4), this yields the accessibility of $p$ from $D$: any end-cut $\alpha$ of $\Delta$ that ends at $p$ is eventually in $U \subset D$; i.e., for $t\neq 1$ but sufficiently close to 1, $\alpha(t) \in U \subset D$.

For the construction of the Jordan region, first choose two accessible points $a$ and $b$ in the interior of $\gamma$, one before $p$ and the other after $p$, based on the natural order along the simple arc $\gamma$. (Such points $a$ and $b$ exist because, by the result, Newman[162, line -3], they are dense in $\partial D$.) Denote the simple subarc of $\gamma$, between $a$ and $b$, by $\gamma'$. Then choose any cross-cut $J'$ of $D$ with endpoints $a$ and $b$. (Such a cross-cut exists by the result, Newman[163, line 13].) Let $J$ be the closed Jordan curve whose image is $\gamma' \cup J'$. By the Jordan Curve Theorem (Newman[115]-Theorem V.10.2), the complement of $J$ consists of two disjoint regions, say $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$, and $J$ is the complete boundary of each of them. Since $p$ is in $J$, it is in the boundary of both of these Jordan
regions.

By Newman[118]-Theorem V.11.7, $D \setminus J'$ consists of two subregions, denoted $D_1$ and $D_2$, and $J'$ lies in the boundary of each of them. It will now be shown that each $D_i$ ($i = 1, 2$) is contained in a distinct $\Delta_j$ ($j = 1, 2$). Since $\gamma' \subset \partial D$ and $J = \gamma' \cup J'$, then
$D \setminus J' = D \setminus J$. Therefore, since $D_1$ is connected and doesn't meet $J$, then $D_1 \subset \Delta_1$ or $\Delta_2$. Similarly, $D_2 \subset \Delta_1$ or $\Delta_2$. Suppose, for the sake of a contradiction, that both $D_1, D_2 \subset \Delta_i$, for $i=1$ or $2$; say $i=1$ for concreteness. Let $q$ be an interior point of $J'$ and $\varepsilon>0$ such that the open disc $D(q;\varepsilon) \subset D$. Then $D(q;\varepsilon) \setminus J' = D(q;\varepsilon) \setminus J$ must contain a point of $\Delta_2$; but
$D(q;\varepsilon) \setminus J' = [D(q;\varepsilon)\cap D_1] \cup [D(q;\varepsilon)\cap D_2] \subset \Delta_1$ (the latter by assumption), which contradicts the disjointness of $\Delta_1$, $\Delta_2$. Thus each of $D_1$, $D_2$ is contained in a distinct $\Delta_j$ ($j = 1, 2$). By switching the subscripts on $D_1$, $D_2$, if necessary, we have $D_1 \subset \Delta_1$, $D_2 \subset \Delta_2$.

Now, for all $0 < \varepsilon < \textrm{dist}(p, J')$, $D(p;\varepsilon)$ contains a point of $D\setminus J'$. Therefore, either $\forall\varepsilon>0$ $D(p;\varepsilon)$ contains a point of $D_1 \subset \Delta_1$ or $\forall\varepsilon>0$ $D(p;\varepsilon)$ contains a point of $D_2 \subset \Delta_2$. If only the latter case holds then change notation, replacing the subscript 2 on both $D_2$, $\Delta_2$ by the subscript 1. Thus we obtain that
$\forall\varepsilon>0$ $D(p;\varepsilon)$ contains a point of $D_1 \subset \Delta_1$.

Next, a neighbourhood basis at $p$, in the space $\Delta_1 \cup \{p\}$, consisting of *connected* open sets is constructed. By the result Newman[163, line 13], $\Delta_1$ is locally connected at its boundary
point $p$: $\forall \varepsilon > 0\ \exists\, \delta > 0$ such that any two points of $\Delta_1 \cap D(p; \delta)$ lie in a connected subset of
$\Delta_1 \cap D(p; \varepsilon)$; without loss of generality, we can assume that $\delta < \varepsilon$. For any such $\varepsilon$ and a chosen (fixed) corresponding $\delta$, we choose some point $x \in \Delta_1 \cap D(p; \delta)$ and denote the component of $\Delta_1 \cap D(p; \varepsilon)$ that contains $x$, by $U_{\varepsilon}$. The parameter $\delta$ is variable but has been fixed
for each choice of $\varepsilon$, so the dependence of $U_{\varepsilon}$ on $\delta$ is not made explicit. Also, if we replace $x$ with some other
$y \in \Delta_1 \cap D(p; \delta)$, then $x$ and $y$ are contained in some connected subset of$\Delta_1 \cap D(p; \varepsilon)$; so the component of $\Delta_1 \cap D(p; \varepsilon)$ that contains $y$ coincides with that containing $x$, namely, $U_{\varepsilon}$. Therefore $U_{\varepsilon}$ doesn't depend on the choice of $x$ either, and it is suppressed from the notation. Now, since $\Delta_1 \cap D(p; \varepsilon)$ is open, then $U_{\varepsilon}$ is open and by the foregoing,
$\Delta_1 \cap D(p; \delta) \subset U_{\varepsilon} \subset \Delta_1 \cap D(p; \varepsilon)$.
Therefore,
$U_{\varepsilon} \cup \{p\} \supset [\Delta_1 \cap D(p; \delta)] \cup \{p\} 
 = [\Delta_1 \cup \{p\}] \cap D(p; \delta)$,
which is an (open) neighbourhood of $p$ in $\Delta_1 \cup \{p\}$.
Since $U_{\varepsilon}$ is open (in **R**$^2$) and
$U_{\varepsilon} \subset \Delta_1$, then it contains a neighbourhood, within $\Delta_1$, of each of its points. Also, clearly $p$ is in the closure of $U_{\varepsilon}$. Therefore, the sets
$\{U_{\varepsilon} \cup \{p\}: \varepsilon >0\}$, form a neighbourhood basis at $p$ of connected open sets of $\Delta_1 \cup \{p\}$. (It is the connectedness of each $U_{\varepsilon}$, rather than that of each $U_{\varepsilon} \cup \{p\}$ that will be of direct use, below, as well as the form of the neighbourhood basis.)

Next, it will be shown that $U_{\varepsilon} \subset D_1$, for all
$\varepsilon < r$, where
$r := \textrm{dist}(p, (\partial D \setminus \gamma') \cup J')$; clearly $r > 0$. For each such $\varepsilon$ and its associated $\delta$,
$\Delta_1 \cap D(p; \delta) \subset U_{\varepsilon}$ and by the result of the second-previous paragraph, (with $\varepsilon$ there replaced by $\delta$ here), $D(p; \delta)$ contains a point $d \in D_1 \subset \Delta_1$. Therefore,
$d \in D_1 \cap D(p; \delta) \subset \Delta_1 \cap D(p; \delta) \subset U_{\varepsilon}$ and thus $U_{\varepsilon}$ meets $D_1$. Since $U_{\varepsilon} \subset \Delta_1$ then $U_{\varepsilon}$ certainly doesn't meet $\gamma' \subset \partial \Delta_1$. Also, $U_{\varepsilon} \subset \Delta_1 \cap D(p; \varepsilon) \subset D(p; r)$, which does not meet
$(\partial D \setminus \gamma') \cup J'$, by the definition of $r$. Therefore, since $\partial D_1 \subset \partial D \cup J' = \gamma' \cup (\partial D \setminus \gamma') \cup J'$, then $U_{\varepsilon}$ doesn't meet $\partial D_1$. Then, by Newman[73]-Theorem IV.1.3, the connected set $U_{\varepsilon}$ cannot meet $(D_1)^c$; i.e., $U_{\varepsilon} \subset D_1 \subset D$.

Finally, every boundary point of a Jordan domain is accessible from that domain
(Newman[161]-Theorem VI.14.1 and Newman[164]-Theorem VI.14.4). Since $p$ is accessible from the Jordan domain $\Delta_1$, then eventually any end-cut of $\Delta_1$ ending at $p$, must eventually lie in its neighbourhood, $U_{\varepsilon} \cup \{p\}$; i.e., except for the end-cut's end-point, $p$, the end-cut must eventually lie in $U_{\varepsilon} \subset D$. Thus $p$ is accessible from $D$.

***Some definitions and results from Newman's book***

**Definitions of *end-cut* and *cross-cut* of a domain:** If $D$ is a domain then a simple arc $L$, with one end-point on the boundary of $D$ and all its other points in $D$, is called an *end-cut of* $D$. If both end-points are on the boundary of $D$ and the rest in $D$, then the simple arc is called a *cross-cut of* $D$.

**Newman[112]-Theorem V.9.2 (Janiszewski's Theorem):** *Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be
closed subsets of **R**$^2$, with at least one of them being bounded and
$F_1 \cap F_2$ being connected. Then two points that are connected in $F^c_1$ and in $F^c_2$ remain connected in $(F_1 \cup F_2)^c$.* (Cf. the comment following Corollary 1 of Newman[112]-Theorem V.9.2, for this version in ***R***$^2$.)

**Newman[115]-Theorem V.10.1:** *A simple arc $L$ in the plane has a single
complementary domain; i.e., $L^c$ is connected.*

**Newman[115]-Theorem V.10.2 (Jordan Curve Theorem):** *A simple closed curve in the plane has two complementary domains, of each of which it is the complete boundary.*

**Newman[118]-Theorem V.11.6:** *If $L$ is an end-cut in a region $D$ then
$D \setminus L$ is connected (and its boundary is $\partial D \cup L$).*

The part in parentheses is not needed here. The required, other part is an immediate application of Janiszewski's Theorem (Newman[112]-Theorem V.9.2), applied to the closed sets, $L$ and $D^c$.

**Newman[118]-Theorem V.11.7:** *If both end-points of a cross-cut $L$ in a domain $D$ are on the same component of $D^c$, then $D \setminus L$ has two components and $L$ is contained in the boundaries of both of them.*

**Newman[119]-Theorem V.11.8:** *If $D_1$ is one of the complementary domains of a Jordan curve, $J$, and $L$ is a cross-cut in $D_1$ whose end-points divide $J$ into the arcs $L_1$ and $L_2$, then the two components of $D_1 \setminus L$ have the boundaries $L \cup L_1$ and $L \cup L_2$.*

**Definition of *locally connected at a boundary point*:** A domain $D$ is
*locally connected* at its boundary point $x$ if For all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that any two points of $D \cap  D(x; \delta)$ lie in a connected subset of $D \cap D(x; \varepsilon)$. Without loss of generality, we may always assume that $\delta < \varepsilon$.

**Newman[161]-Theorem VI.14.1:** *A Jordan region is locally connected at each of
its boundary points.* (An even stronger property of *uniform* local connectedness holds but we don't need that strengthening.)

**Definition of *accessible* point:** Let $D$ be a domain. A point of the boundary $\partial D$ of a domain $D$ is *accessible* from $D$ if it is an
end-point of an end-cutin $D$.

The following two results are stated (in italics) and proved in the text but are not elevated to the status of a theorem. I will refer to them just by page and line number.

**Newman[162, line -3]:** *The accessible points in the boundary $\partial D$ of
a domain $D$ are dense in $\partial D$.*

**Newman[163, line 13]:** *If $a$ and $b$ are accessible points in the boundary
$\partial D$ of a domain $D$ then there is a cross-cut in $D$ having $a$ and $b$ as its end-points.*

**Newman[164]-Theorem VI.14.4:** *If a domain $D$ is locally connected at its
boundary point $x$ then $x$ is accessible from $D$.*

**Newman[73]-Theorem IV.1.3:** *If A is a connected set (in a topological space)
that meets a set E and its complement, then A meets $\partial E$.*